# Redirecting to a html page from localhost

Tags: javascript, redirect, routes

I have a sign up form on this page `http://localhost:3000/`. I then have a redirect inside a conditional saying:

```
if (!error){
document.location.replace('/welcome.html');
}
```

It then goes to `http://localhost:3000/welcome.html` but in the body says `Cannot GET /welcome.html`

how do I set up routing in JS so that my html pages are linked to url extensions?

Comment: are you trying to do this on xampp?

Answer (score 1):

if it's in the current directory use: (and by current I mean in the same directory as the file referencing the html)

```
./welcome.html
```

if it's in another directory use

```
../other/welcome.html
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this and it still just tried to hit /welcome.html

Comment: And welcome.html is in the root directory of the project? Like the same directory at index.html?

Comment: both in the same root directory yes